# Fluid Powered TYPO3 Builder backend page displaying "Sorry, the requested view was not found."

Tags: content-management-system, typo3, builder, fluid

I installed TYPO3 ver 8.7.3 on my local machine using XAMPP. I want to build a website using Fluid Powered TYPO3, so I started to follow the instructions found in the documentation ( I'm new to this CMS ). I installed some extensions from the github page (https://github.com/FluidTYPO3) : vhs, flux, and builder. In the backend panel there is an icon under Admin Tools to access the Builder extension, yet when I click it there is an error :

```
Sorry, the requested view was not found.

The technical reason is: No template was found. View could not be resolved for action "index" in class "FluidTYPO3\Builder\Controller\BackendController".
```

I researched it thoroughly, and I couldn't find either the solution for this specific problem, nor anything that I could use to deduce anything helpful.

So, what should I do to resolve this ?

Comment: Did you have a typoscript template in your root page?
Where are your fluid templates located? Are you sure that the path is correct?

Comment: I think this is an issue for the builder extension. Ask the extension owner for this problem: https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/builder/issues